# Вывести сначала элементы на четных позициях массива, а затем — на нечетных

Tags: ruby

Здравствуйте, нашёл задачу по Руби, решить её не смог, нашёл решение, но и даже в нём не могу разобраться.

```
m = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
s = (0..m.size-1).to_a
p s.partition{ |i| puts i[0].zero? }.flatten.map{ |i| m[i] }
```

Непонятно как взаимодействует  `.partition`  с  блоком  `{ |i| puts i[0].zero? }`  
Я прочитал документацию и там сказано, что этот метод возвращает 2 массива и в первом массиве содержатся элементы, которые с булевым значением  `true`  (которые отвечают на условие в блоке). Это понятно, но не понимаю условие, почему именно `i[0]` и к нему применяется метод `.zero?` , ведь в первом элементе массива нет значения 0, там 1. Объясните это, пожалуйста.
Так же не понимаю, как работает второй блок. Я был бы очень благодарен за полное разъяснение третьей строки с двумя блоками, самому не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А по простому нельзя?

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
m.each_with_index {|e,i| puts e if i%2 == 0}
m.each_with_index {|e,i| puts e if i%2 != 0}
```

В вашем решении:

```
s = (0..m.size-1).to_a
```

Теперь `s` — это массив, состоящий из чисел, являющихся индексами элементов. Короче говоря `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`.

Если у целого числа вызвать метод `[0]`, то мы получим последний символ в двоичной записи этого числа

```
2.1.4 :018 > 2[0]
 => 0 
2.1.4 :019 > 3[0]
 => 1
```

Именно этим мы пользуемся в блоке метода `partition`. `i[0].zero?` вернёт `true` для чётных индексов, и `false` для нечётных. То есть, как вы совершенно правильно рассказали про `partition`, делим массив на два — сперва чётные номера, потом нечётные.

```
s.partition{ |i| i[0].zero? }
=> [[0, 2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

`flaten` просто вытаскивает все вложенные элементы и выстраивает их в однородный массив. У нас получится массив индексов. Осталось только вытащить из `m` элементы с этими индексами с помощью `.map{ |i| m[i] }`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, так гораздо понятливей.

Comment: Не за что. Рассказал про ваше решение.

Comment: Огромное спасибо ещё и за разъяснение того примера. installero, а с Вами можно как-нибудь связаться? Скайп, например, или соц. сеть.

Comment: В профиле всё есть

Comment: Я не понимаю, как работает пример Вашей программы. К примеру, вторая строка. Выводит элемент, если индекс делится на 2 без остатка. По моей логике, без остатка делятся 2, 4 и 6 индексы и должны, соответственно, выводиться такие элементы, как: 3, 5, 7, но программа выводит так: 1, 3, 5, 7. 
На третьей строке делятся на 2 без остатка такие индексы: 0, 1, 3, 5 (соответствующие элементы 1, 2, 4, 6), почему программа выводит 2, 4, 6?

Comment: 0 делится на 2 без остатка

Comment: всё понятно теперь, спасибо большое, что-то я тупанул

Comment: Никогда не торопитесь принимать ответы как верные.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по *решению*, которое вы нашли, требовалось смотреть не на четность самих эл-нтов, а на четность их позиций.

```
a = %w{ a b c d e f g h }
p a.partition.with_index{ |c, i| i.odd? }
```

> [["b", "d", "f", "h"], ["a", "c", "e", "g"]]

Comment: Да, я уже понял это. Спасибо за ответ.